# Can beta-features be added to the app on the App Store?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

We are working on an iOS app which is already on the App Store. We are planning some new features for the app. Can we add these unfinished features in a beta mode? Will Apple allow this?

Answer (score 2):

## No Demos, Betas, or Trial Versions

From the App Store Review Guidelines …

> ### [2.2 Beta Testing](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#beta-testing)
>
> Demos, betas, and trial versions of your app don’t belong on the App Store – use TestFlight instead.

Still unsure? Only Apple can answer this question authoritatively. Please [contact Apple iTunes Connect team](http://www.apple.com/itunes/go/itunesconnect/contactus/) directly and ask.

Comment: The app in itself is not Beta. We are talking about Beta features.

Comment: **You should ask Apple directly.** I suspect Apple will ask you to use TestFlight for any beta features. The App Store is for finished products. Please let us know the outcome; it may be helpful to others.

Comment: @MitulJindal did you find out an answer to this?